# How to model hierarchical data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a bunch of types where their hierarchy stores some useful information. I'm trying to avoid having to bake in knowledge of the hierarchy of the types into the functions that operate on them.

The following is a little excerpt of Stanford's Typed Dependencies for natural language processing:

```
root - root
dep - dependent
  aux - auxiliary
    auxpass - passive auxiliary 
    cop - copula
  arg - argument 
    agent - agent
```

I would like to create some data types that mirror this structure so that I can define some functions that can only operate on certain types. When I have a function that operates on an `arg`, the type that I use to represent `arg` should also include `agent` but the type for `agent` should not include `arg`. The type for `dep` should include anything below it.

Is this possible in haskell? I've been trying to declare various `data` types to model this, but I can't get it to work since a data type cannot use the constructor of another data type.

I suspect that maybe this approach doesn't work very well with Haskell, so if that's the case how do you usually deal with these cases where flattening the hierarchy is definitely undesirable?

Comment: The simplest approach would be having `Arg` datatype that has an `Agent` field. Would that be insufficient?

Comment: @danidiaz That would contradict this requirement: "When I have a function that operates on an arg, the type that I use to represent arg should also include agent".

Comment: this might be an interesting related read: https://wiki.haskell.org/OOP_vs_type_classes

Comment: The best approach I have seen in "practice" to solving this problem is the subtyping as defined in subhask. Essentially, you define a typeclass to represent subtype relationships (and a few difficult-to-implement choice instances to get the transitivity property) which has only an 'embed' function.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/subhask-0.1.1.0/docs/SubHask-SubType.html

Comment: Do you have any actual fields in these classes/types?

Comment: @Alec all types will have a text field, members of `dep` have an additional relation field. What's important is that the type itself is conveying some useful information about the context of the relation. The context gets more specific the further down the hierarchy you travel.

Comment: @SamP, this is interesting. "The type itself is conveying some useful information ...".  In constructive logic, information comes with witness. E.g. if for every A there is a B such that..., there will be a witness function `A -> B`.  Find the witnesses of your "useful information", and you might get insight into how to model it.

Answer (score 1):

Subtyping in general does not play too well with Haskell. However, in the case that you are just trying to model (non-multiple) inheritance (so you have a tree of subtypes instead of a lattice), you can actually build sub typing up using type classes. [Here is a short gist that does exactly this.](https://gist.github.com/harpocrates/38ec83098cd45d7e8bccbb2d7001acb5#file-subtype-hs) Working from there, you define your data types

```
data Root = Root ...
data Dep = Dependent ...
data Aux = Auxiliary ...
data AuxPass = PassiveAuxiliary ... 
data Cop = Copula ...
data Arg = Argument ...
data Agent = Agent ...
```

And the corresponding instances

```
instance Subtype Aux where
  type SuperType Aux = Dep
  embedImmediate = ...

instance Subtype AuxPass where
  type SuperType AuxPass = Aux
  embedImmediate = ...

instance Subtype Cop where
  type SuperType Cop = Aux
  embedImmediate = ...

instance Subtype Arg where
  type SuperType Arg = Dep
  embedImmediate = ...

instance Subtype Agent where
  type SuperType Agent = Arg
  embedImmediate = ...
```

How you fill in the `...` is up to you. A couple things you could do for this:

- if your subtype adds lots of fields on top of the supertype, consistently, just add to it a field that has the supertype and make `embedImmediate` return that field
- if your subtype adds only a couple of fields, you might want to manually unpack them. Your `data` definitions will look neater, but your `embedImmediate` definition will be a bit longer
- if your subtypes doesn't add any fields to the supertype, you can just make a `newtype` around the super type and `embedImmediate = coerce` (from `Data.Coerce`)

Then, you can't *quite* just use the subtypes in functions that expect supertypes, but almost: you just have to add a call to `embed` (different from `embedImmediate`!) to convert from the subtype to whichever supertype is needed (based on type inference). You may want to check out [some example uses](https://gist.github.com/harpocrates/38ec83098cd45d7e8bccbb2d7001acb5#file-subtype-examples-hs).

Note that you can now use `<:` as a constraint: the type of something that is a subtype of `Aux`, for example, is `(a <: Aux) => a`. Whenever you want this thing treated as an `Aux` (or a super type of `Aux`), call `embed` on it.

The one big downside of this approach is that the input and output types must be annotated (else it isn't clear *which* supertype you want to `embed` into and you'll get "ambiguous type" errors). If you already write lots of signatures, you should be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Use typeclasses.

First define each of the concrete types as a seperate data declaration.

Then for each type with subtypes declare a typeclass with a constraint on its parent. An example of this sort of relationship is Functor =>  Applicative => Monad structure in prelude.

So to define the example structure:

```
class Root where
    ...

class Root => Dep where
    ...

class Dep => Aux where
    ...

class Aux => Auxpass where
    ...

class Aux => Cop where
    ...

class Dep => Arg where
    ...

class Arg => Agent where
    ...
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I get that this isn't the ideal use of a type class, but is there an alternative? Would this + GADT not do it?

Comment: Not a downvoter but probably because you are using type classes merely as a means of overloading (and not as an abstraction). I wouldn't recommend this approach, but I don't think pointing it out is a bad idea