# How to apply incremental specificity, using subclassing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, subclassing

I'm trying to use subclassing, in Haskell, to apply incremental specificity to my classes and having no luck.

My first attempt:

```
module Subclassing where

class SuperClass a where
  type TheType a :: *
  theFunc :: TheType a -> TheType a

class SuperClass b => SubClass b where
  type TheType b = Int

data MyType

instance SubClass MyType where
  theFunc x = x + x
```

yielded this:

```
Subclassing.hs:10:8: error:
    ‘TheType’ is not a (visible) associated type of class ‘SubClass’

Subclassing.hs:15:3: error:
    ‘theFunc’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘SubClass’
```

I wondered if there was some syntactical method for exposing the superclass' types/methods to the subclass. So, I searched around a bit on the net, but didn't find anything.

In my second attempt, I tried to force the issue, by defining a universal instance of the superclass, constrained on the subclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances   #-}

module Subclassing where

class SuperClass a where
  type TheType a :: *
  theFunc :: TheType a -> TheType a

class SubClass b
instance SubClass c => SuperClass c where
  type TheType c = Int

data MyType

instance SubClass MyType
instance SuperClass MyType where
  theFunc x = x + x

testFunc :: SuperClass d => [TheType d] -> TheType d
testFunc = sum . (map theFunc)
```

It yielded this:

```
Subclassing2.hs:25:23: error:
    • Overlapping instances for SuperClass a0
        arising from a use of ‘theFunc’
      Matching givens (or their superclasses):
        SuperClass d
          bound by the type signature for:
                     testFunc :: SuperClass d => [TheType d] -> TheType d
          at Subclassing2.hs:24:1-52
      Matching instances:
        instance SubClass c => SuperClass c
          -- Defined at Subclassing2.hs:15:10
        instance SuperClass MyType -- Defined at Subclassing2.hs:21:10
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘a0’)
    • In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘theFunc’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(map theFunc)’
      In the expression: sum . (map theFunc)
```

In my third attempt, I tried making the subclass a type rather than a class.
(I realized that this would have limited applicability, due to the single field limitation of the *newtype* value constructor, but was out of ideas.):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes    #-}

module Subclassing where

class SuperClass a where
  type TheType a :: *
  theFunc :: TheType a -> TheType a

newtype SubClass = SubClass { unSubClass :: Int -> Int }
instance SuperClass SubClass where
  type TheType SubClass = Int
  theFunc = unSubClass

testFunc :: SuperClass d => [TheType d] -> TheType d
testFunc = sum . (map theFunc)
```

And it yielded this:

```
Subclassing3.hs:17:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int -> Int’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: TheType SubClass -> TheType SubClass
        Actual type: SubClass -> Int -> Int
    • In the expression: unSubClass
      In an equation for ‘theFunc’: theFunc = unSubClass
      In the instance declaration for ‘SuperClass SubClass’

Subclassing3.hs:20:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘TheType a0’ with ‘TheType d’
      Expected type: TheType a0 -> TheType d
        Actual type: TheType a0 -> TheType a0
      NB: ‘TheType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘theFunc’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(map theFunc)’
      In the expression: sum . (map theFunc)
    • Relevant bindings include
        testFunc :: [TheType d] -> TheType d
          (bound at Subclassing3.hs:20:1)
```

Comment: I think you haven't quite grokked what a class _is_. A Haskell type-class is very different from a class in typical OO languages. Defining an _instance_ of a class (which can be done for concrete types, as the newtype in your third attempt) is fundamentally different from defining a subclass of it.

Comment: To give an answer to this probably [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question, it would be useful to know a bit more about what you want all this for. In particular, the type family `TheType` doesn't seem to make any sense; why do you think you need an associated type family there?

Comment: This is definitely not something Haskell is built to support. That said, I made a [proof of concept gist](https://gist.github.com/harpocrates/38ec83098cd45d7e8bccbb2d7001acb5#file-subtype-hs) about this a while ago. If that is what you are looking for, the question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41504364/3072788.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first guess seems sensible enough to me, but no, Haskell doesn't let one define associated types or methods in a (sub)class definition.